# Passing Data From Broadcast receiver to composable screen

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have setup geofence through my viewmodel of compose screen and have broadcast receiver to receive different geofence event. I am successfully receiving data in onReceive() now I want to update my composable screen UI State. How can I achieve this?

```
class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            val errorMessage = GeofenceStatusCodes
                .getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.errorCode)
            return
        }
        val geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {         
           /* Update UI State from here */           
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Hold the data in some repository and offer it from view model.